# Modificar consulta de selección

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

He replantiado la pregunta y voy a poner un ejemplo mas simple para poder dejarme enteder.

Tengo la siguiente consulta de selección `SELECT`

```
SELECT PC.ProductoCatalogoId, P.Nombre, PC.PrecioVenta, E.Nombre, O.NombreOpcion
FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC
INNER JOIN Productos AS P
ON PC.ProductoId = P.ProductoId
INNER JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC
ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId
INNER JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP
ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId
INNER JOIN Especificaciones AS E
ON EP.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId
INNER JOIN Opciones AS O
ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId
WHERE P.Nombre LIKE '%CAM%'
```

Imagen
[image: captura3]

En esa consulta traigo una camiseta ingresada al Catalogo la cual muestra que solo hay en talla S y en los colores rojo y azul(esto quiere decir que el rojo y el azul son talla S)

Entonces solo me sirven la segunda y tercera fila porque la primera solo indica la talla.

Debo de mostrar al usuario algo como esto:

```
1 CAMISETA FERRARI 12.00 TALLA LETRA S COLOR ROJO
1 CAMISETA FERRARI 12.00 TALLA LETRA S COLOR AZUL
```

NOTA: La consulta que muestro me da tres filas como resultado, pero lo que necesito mostrar es la segunda y tercera fila en el formato que estoy mostrando.

Estructura de tablas

[image: maestro]

¿Como puedo hacer para que me salga en el formato que necesito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así te serviria?:

```
SELECT distinct(PC.ProductoCatalogoId),
    P.Nombre,
    PC.PrecioVenta,
    PL.Product + ' ' + E.Nombre + ' ' + O.NombreOpcion
FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC
INNER JOIN Productos AS P ON PC.ProductoId = P.ProductoId
INNER JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId 
INNER JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId
INNER JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON EP.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId
AND E.EspecificacionId = 2
INNER JOIN Opciones AS O ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT E.Nombre + ' ' + O.NombreOpcion AS 'Product'
    FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC
    INNER JOIN Productos AS P ON PC.ProductoId = P.ProductoId
    INNER JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId
    INNER JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId
    INNER JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON EP.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId
        AND E.EspecificacionId IN (5)
    INNER JOIN Opciones AS O ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId

    ) PL
    WHERE P.Nombre LIKE '%FERR%'
```

> NOTA: En vez de validar en el CASE el nombre de la especificación,
>   podrías validar por el Id.

Solo es un ejemplo ya que no puedo probarlo realmente como tal.

Me comentas que tal va.

> El Producto Pantalon, tiene muchas tallas y al parecer tiene ligado un color  por talla, y aparte tienen 2 precios diferentes, por eso es que se repite muchas veces, debido a que es un color por talla, mientras que la camisa solo tiene una talla y 2 colores ligados.

Espero sea lo que necesitas.

Comment: Me da error en el segunda as del select case

Comment: Listo, corregido.

Comment: Es así como sale https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArSzlnjk6KJwh51fbBneZJZgSBt51w

Comment: Edité mi respuesta, creo que es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Hola así era como quería que sea solo que por ejempo en camiseta solo tengo registrado la talla S en color rojo y azul y tu consulta me trae tallas en números los cuales no están registrados.

Comment: Me podrías mostrar lo que te arroja mi query?

Comment: En la pregunta puedes ver los registros que trae son solo tres pero en tu consutla me trae muchos datos es mas que no corresponden al producto.   https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArSzlnjk6KJwh51g2DEGnrJdRl3GdA

Comment: ¿Eso que es Pedro?

Comment: Subí la base de datos a la nube y eso son las credenciales para que te puedas conectar.

Comment: He intentado con pivot pero me parece que tengo que hacer dos pivot uno para color y otro para talla

Comment: Modifiqué mi respuesta, espero y te sirva.

Comment: Así es la camiseta solo tiene dos colores por talla y debe salir dos registros pero sale mas de dos registros. Y en el pantalón efectivamente es por color, talla y ciertas tallas tienen otro precio.

Comment: Modifique la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que agrupalar los campos pero antes tienes que hacer una consulta anidada mas o menos asi,

```
SELECT 
    A.ProductoCatalogoId,
    A.Nombre,
    A.PrecioVenta,
    A.NOMBREFull
FROM(
    SELECT 
        PC.ProductoCatalogoId, 
        P.Nombre, 
        PC.PrecioVenta, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,E.Nombre+' '+O.NombreOpcion) AS NOMBREFull
    FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC
    INNER JOIN Productos AS P
    ON PC.ProductoId = P.ProductoId
    INNER JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC
    ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId
    INNER JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP
    ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId
    INNER JOIN Especificaciones AS E
    ON EP.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId
    INNER JOIN Opciones AS O
    ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId
    WHERE P.Nombre LIKE '%MAC%') A
GROUP BY A.ProductoCatalogoId, A.Nombre, A.PrecioVenta, A.NOMBREFull
```

Espero que te funcione

Comment: No sale como lo necesito, considera que en el campo E.Nombre tengo registrado las tallas(talla letra, talla número) y color

Comment: En la tabla Especificaciones tengo un campo Nombre en el cual registro las especificaciones de los productos  como: talla número, talla letra, color, etc tendría que buscar la manera de poder diferenciarlos para poder tomarlo cuando es talla número, color.

Comment: He modificado la pregunta